# Is there a non-named pipes in windows api?

Tags: c++, pipe, windows

Posix provided both named and non-named pipes... Can you have a non-named pipes and windows and how to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  They are called "Anonymous Pipes" in the Windows API documentation.  For more details, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365137%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can: `CreatePipe()` (vs. `CreateNamedPipe()`).